# MYSQL: left join in two tables using distinct value from one table

Tags: mysql, group-by, left-join

I want to join two tables having a common column stationcode(TABLE vfdefects & tempsubstation).
The problem is tempsubstation has duplicate column values while i only want the count of each unique values. With my current attempts it is doubling the value for duplicate entries using `LEFT JOIN` and `GROUP BY`

`TABLE A`
`ID|stationID|CODE`

`TABLE B`
`A|B|C|D|stationcode`

The query is as follows:

```
SELECT DISTINCT     TS.substationid,'20130924',ts.employeeid,ts.substationcode,ts.manufacturingproductid,ts.assemblylineid,ts.teamid,ts.subofficecode,
TA.AllowID,ta.OtherAllowanceID,ta.allowname,ta.minbenchmark,ta.maxbenchmark,COUNT(vfd.DefectsID) Achieved

FROM tempsubstation ts
LEFT JOIN TempAllowances ta ON ts.manufacturingproductid=ta.manufacturingproductid AND ts.subofficecode=ta.subofficecode AND ta.teamid=ts.teamid
LEFT JOIN wms_assemblyqcmapping aqc ON ts.subofficeid=aqc.subofficeid AND ts.manufacturingproductid=aqc.manufacturingproductid AND ts.assemblylineid=aqc.assemblylineid
LEFT JOIN wms_vfdefects vfd ON vfd.QCStationCode=aqc.QCStationCode AND ts.SubstationCode =vfd.MFGStationNum AND DATE(vfd.CreationDate)='2013-09-24'
WHERE ta.AllowID=42
 GROUP BY ta.minbenchmark,ta.maxbenchmark,ts.substationid
 HAVING COUNT(vfd.DefectsID)>=ta.minbenchmark AND COUNT(vfd.DefectsID)<=ta.maxbenchmark
```

Comment: join with a subquery that removes the duplicates

Comment: i am using temporary tables and i cannot refer it again in a subquery while running the parent query too. is there another way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
FROM tempsubstation ts
```

to:

```
FROM (SELECT * FROM tempsubstation
      GROUP BY columnWithDuplicateValues) ts
```

Answer (score -1):

How are you running the query? if via PHP then simplify the SQL and run a second SQL in the PHP read loop.